# Syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting :: or '[' or '.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
row = Hash[new_hash.map { |k, v| k, v.encode("UTF-16BE", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?').encode("UTF-8") }]
```

This line in a controller causes an syntax error, but I can't find any mistakes. Can anyone figure out what's going wrong?

This is a Rails application. `Ruby 2.2.0` and `Rails 4.2.0`.

Comment: As an aside: in Ruby 2.2 you can probably just use [`String#scrub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-scrub) to remove invalid bytes rather than encoding to UTF-16 and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot brackets (`[]`). It should be:

```
row = Hash[new_hash.map{ |k, v| [k, v.encode("UTF-16BE", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?').encode("UTF-8")] }]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Marek Lipka. I'm new to programming itself, so I often stack problems like this. Anyway, I appreciate to solve this.